# Как вводить данные до старта сцены Unity, если классы наследуются от MonoBehaviour?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Делаю tower defence игру на юнити. В ней нужно, чтобы определенные мобы спавнились по волнам.
Во всех гайдах, которые я смотрел, между спавном каждого моба одинаковая задержка, а надо, чтобы было возможно спавнить их по группам без задержки.

Вот скриншоты, чтобы было понятнее.
Как в гайдах
[image]

Как мне надо
[image]

Для этого я сделал менеджер волн.

```
public class WavesManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LevelData levelData;
    public List<Wave> waves;
    private int currentWaveIndex = -1;

    private void Awake()
    {
        waves = levelData.waves;
    }

    public void StartNextWave()
    {
        currentWaveIndex++;
        if (currentWaveIndex == waves.Count) return;
        waves[currentWaveIndex].Spawn(levelData.pieces);
    }
}
```

Вот класс самой волны

```
[Serializable]
public class Wave : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Squad> squads = new();

    public void Spawn(List<Piece> pieces)
    {
        StartCoroutine(nameof(SpawnSquads), pieces);
    }

    private IEnumerator SpawnSquads(List<Piece> pieces)
    {
        foreach (var squad in squads)
        {
            squad.Spawn(pieces);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(squad.otherSquadDelay);
        }
    }
}
```

И отряд

```
[Serializable]
public class Squad : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string enemyTitle;
    public int amount;
    public int innerDelay;
    public int otherSquadDelay;

    public void Spawn(List<Piece> pieces)
    {
        StartCoroutine(nameof(SpawnEnemies), pieces);
    }

    private IEnumerator SpawnEnemies(IEnumerable<Piece> pieces)
    {
        var piece = pieces.Select(x => x)
            .First(x => x.title == enemyTitle);
        for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            piece.Spawn();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(innerDelay);
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что я не могу понять, как мне настраивать заранее кто и как будет спавниться в сквадах из-за наследования от MonoBehaviour, а убрать его нельзя так как не будет работать корутина.

Вот еще скрипт, в который я заранее ввожу данные волн и сквадов.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "LevelData", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/LevelData")]
public class LevelData : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<Piece> pieces;
    public List<Wave> waves;
}
```

Comment: Как по мне, `Squad` - лишнее, задержка должна быть отдельно. И корутина switch-case "если задержка - жду, если юнит, беру префаб и спавню, выполняю минимальную задержку между спавном юнитов, чтоб ненаспавнить в одну точку". И всё, финальное решение должно стать ещё проще, чем вы показали. Минимального ООП должно хватить. А из них уже спавнить SO с префабами, количествами и задержками, которые будет кушать корутина. В Unity не шарю, поэтому на гениальность не претендую. А про `MonoBehavior` не понял, при чем он тут.

Comment: @aepot Дело в том, что если класс **не** наследуется от MonoBehaviour, то в юнити в инспекторе можно по отдельности настроить *каждое* его публичное или помеченное аттрибутом [SerializeField] поле, а вот если он наследуется, то можно только указать ссылку на только один конкретный заранее построенный и сохраненный объект (префаб).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю следующую реализацию.

---

Классы `Wave` и `Squad` пусть просто хранят информацию. Они не будут MonoBehaviour.

```
public class Wave
{
    [SerializeField] private List<Squad> squads = new List<Squad>();

    // Количество сквадов в волне
    public int CountSquads => squads.Count;

    public Squad GetSquad (int index)
    {
        return squads[index];
    }
}
```

```
[Serializable]
public class Squad
{
    public string enemyTitle;
    public int amount;
    public int innerDelay;
    public int otherSquadDelay;
}
```

Зачем в LevelData нужен список Pieces я не совсем понял, поэтому удалил его, он мне не пригодился. Если он вам нужен, добавьте.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "LevelData", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/LevelData", order =51)]
public class LevelData : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<Wave> waves;
}
```

Я создал класс `EnemiesSpawner`, который хранит ссылки на префабы разных врагов и умеет спавнить этих самых врагов:

```
public class EnemiesSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Префабы врагов
    [SerializeField] private GameObject GoblinPrefab, OrcPrefab, HellHoundPrefab;

    public void SpawnPiece (GameObject piece)
    {
        Vector3 positions = new Vector3(0, 0, 0); // Настройки, которые вам нужны

        Instantiate(piece, positions, Quaternion.identity); // Спавним определенного врага
    }

    // Функция спавна врага по его имени title
    public void SpawnPiece(string title)
    {
        SpawnPiece(GetPieceByTitle(title));
    }

    // Функция получения префаба врага по его имени title
    private GameObject GetPieceByTitle (string title)
    {
        // Здесь нужно получать префаб врага (piece) по его имени (title)
        // Простейший способ -- switch case, но, наверно, вам стоит сделать словарик.

        switch (title)
        {
            case "Goblin":
                return GoblinPrefab;
            case "Orc":
                return OrcPrefab;
            case "HellHound":
                return HellHoundPrefab;
            // И т.д.
            default:
                throw new System.Exception("Unknown nemy title");
        }
    }
}
```

Класс `WavesManager` будет, исходя из названия, контролировать процесс спавна волн:

```
public class WavesManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Level data")]
    [SerializeField] private LevelData _levelData;

    [Header("References")]
    [SerializeField] private EnemiesSpawner _spawner;

    private List<Wave> _waves;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _waves = _levelData.waves;

        StartCoroutine(SpawningProcess());
    }

    private IEnumerator SpawningProcess()
    {
        // Проходим по волнам
        foreach (Wave wave in _waves)
        {
            // Проходим по сквадам
            for (int i = 0; i < wave.CountSquads; i++)
            {
                Squad currSquad = wave.GetSquad(i);
                // Проходим по врагам в скваде
                for (int j = 0; j < currSquad.amount; j++)
                {
                    _spawner.SpawnPiece(currSquad.enemyTitle); // Спавним врага

                    if (j < currSquad.amount - 1)
                        yield return new WaitForSeconds(currSquad.innerDelay); // Задержка между врагами в скваде
                }

                if (i < wave.CountSquads - 1)
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(currSquad.otherSquadDelay); // Задержка между сквадами
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3); // Время между волнами
        }
    }
}
```

---

Некоторые комментарии:

1. Не советую хранить название врагов в строке string. Во-первых, легко опечататься, во-вторых, вообще плохая практика. Советую выбрать или перечисления enum, или вообще указывать в инспекторе сразу префабы врагов, то есть вместо переменной `string enemyTitle` сделать `GameObject EnemyPrefab` и его же и спавнить. Так нам даже не понадобится функция GetPieceByTitle.
2. Я не увидел в вашем коде задержку между волнами, поэтому просто поставил ее равной 2 секундам. Думаю, она мжет отличаться от уровня к уровню, поэтому можно сделать переменную `otherWaveDealy` в классе `Wave`. Тогда в классу `WaveManager` строку `yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);` нужно заменить на `yield return new WaitForSeconds(wave.otherWaveDelay);`
3. Я сделал переменную squads приватной, ибо нефиг ей быть публичной, чтобы ее можно было изменять из сторонних классов. Я добавил геттер количества волн CountSquad и геттер конкретной i-й волны `GetSquad(index)`. Получается более надежный механизм: из других классов получать волны можно, но изменять нельзя.

Comment: Все отлично работает, но как сделать так, чтобы была возможность одновременно спавнить несколько сквадов?